# PHP fopen an Unicode encoded file from a different encoded page

Tags: php, character-encoding, fopen

I have a text file stored in a server which is encoded in UTF-8 and im trying to load that file from a webpage in another server which is encoded in shift_JIS. I cant get it to work though. This is my original code:

```
function whatever() {
 $open_file = fopen("http://www.myass.com/whatever.txt", 'r');
 $whatevers = explode("*", fgets($open_file));
 $whatevers_num =count($whatevers)-2;
 $i=1;
 while($i <= $whatevers_num) {
   $details = explode("|", $whatevers[$i++]);
   echo <<<EOF
   $details[1] - $details[2] - $details[3]
EOF;
 }
  fclose($open_file);
}
```

I tried by doing this:

```
function whatever() {
 $open_file = fopen(mb_convert_encoding("http://www.myass.com/whatever.txt", "shift_jis"), 'r');
 $whatevers = explode("*", fgets($open_file));
 $whatevers_num =count($whatevers)-2;
 $i=1;
 while($i <= $whatevers_num) {
   $details = explode("|", $whatevers[$i++]);
   echo <<<EOF
   $details[1] - $details[2] - $details[3]
EOF;
 }
  fclose($open_file);
}
```

and even this:

```
function whatever() {
 $open_file = fopen("http://www.myass.com/whatever.txt", 'r');
 $whatevers = explode("*", fgets($open_file));
 $whatevers_num =count($whatevers)-2;
 $i=1;
 while($i <= $whatevers_num) {
   $details = explode("|", $whatevers[$i++]);
   echo <<<EOF
   $details[1] - $details[2] - $details[3]
EOF;
 }
  fclose($open_file);
}

ob_start();
whatever();
$get_whatever = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$encode = mb_convert_encoding("$get_whatever", "shift_jis");

echo $encode;
```

but nothing worked, i get only garbled characters. What can i do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend loading the entire content of the file (using `file_get_contents` or CURL) into a string and converting it before doing any other type of processing.  This ensures you have the full converted text at hand.

```
$utf_string = file_get_contents('http://www.myass.com/whatever.txt');
$sjis_string = mb_convert_encoding($utf_string, 'SJIS', 'UTF-8');
echo($sjis_string);
```

After this, you can start your `explode` and loop logic.